# How to add contact in phone contact programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contacts

I have a program that some person send to my whats app a serial key and then I add them with my program,now I want Add contacts in phone contact with my program.
please help me that do it.thanks

Comment: with one google search I found this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html
http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html
http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html